# Equivalent of java.net.URLConnection in .NET

Tags: java, .net, urlconnection

Is there an equivalent of the [`java.net.URLConnection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) class
in .NET. , for example the `HttpWebRequest`? What else could be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the closest is:

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url); // note this is IDisposable so
                                         // should be in a "using" block, or
                                         // otherwise disposed.
```

since this will handle multiple protocols etc. But if you are meaning http - I'd use `WebClient`; it is much simpler than `HttpWebRequest` (one of the `WebRequest` implementations).

If all you want is to download a page:

```
string s;
using(var client = new WebClient()) {
    s = client.DownloadString(url);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) and [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) are as close as I can see.

Is there a specific feature or set of features that you require?

Comment: It is just to establish a connection to a site and to download data, as far as I understand

Comment: @Jan-Frederik Carl - `WebClient` will do just that.

Comment: I need an equivalent of setRequestProperty