# Bad request 400 for json

Tags: json

I am trying to export to file the json output of a url.  But starting with parsing the json output, I got an error of Bad request.  I can't understand why, because when i manually input the url on web, it has a valid result.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;

namespace web
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var json = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?country=DE&currency=3&appid=570&market_hash_name=Helm%20of%20the%20Guardian%20Construct");
            Console.WriteLine(json);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a .net expert, but this is a GET operation...are your query parameters correct?

Comment: Yes.  When I type it in the url bar of google chrome, it returns a json result.

Comment: But you also need to open a connection first. See this thread.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345340/equivalent-of-java-net-urlconnection-in-net

Comment: I still got bad request using code from the link you provide

string s;
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                s = client.DownloadString("http://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?country=DE&currency=3&appid=570&market_hash_name=Helm%20of%20the%20Guardian%20Construct");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            Console.ReadLine();

Comment: Well, the URL gives me a bad request.(check in Developers console) You are not allowed beyond https://steamcommunity.com/market/. Probably because you are missing authorization call before this call.

Comment: Ohhhh..... So, the reason why i get valid result when i typed it in my web client is because i have credentials already saved on the web client...

Comment: Exactly. So before you can do a GET, you need to make an authorization call. Good Luck.